# Typescript typings, generics and abstract classes

Tags: generics, typescript, abstract, typescript-typings

I experiment a behavior that seems strange to me.

Let's consider the following sample ([test it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20FooAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20bar()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20extends%20FooAbstract%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20bar%3A%20%27bar%27%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FooMaker%3CFOO%20extends%20FooAbstract%3E%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20foo%3A%20FOO)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.foo.bar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.foo.bar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20foo.bar()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foomaker%20%3D%20new%20FooMaker(new%20Foo)%3B%0D%0Alet%20result1%20%3D%20foomaker.foo%3B%0D%0Alet%20result2%20%3D%20foomaker.foo.bar()%3B%0D%0Alet%20result3%20%3D%20foomaker.bar()%3B%0D%0Alet%20result4%20%3D%20foomaker.baz()%3B%20%2F%2F%20I%27ve%20seen%20comments%20about%20using%20a%20lambda...%20Not%20better%0D%0A)):

```
abstract class FooAbstract {
    abstract bar() {}
}

class Foo extends FooAbstract { 
    bar() { 
        return { bar: 'bar' };
    }
}

class FooMaker<FOO extends FooAbstract> {  
    constructor(public foo: FOO) {}

    bar() { 
        return this.foo.bar();
    }

    baz = () => { 
        return this.foo.bar();
    }
}

let foo = new Foo();
let result = foo.bar();

let foomaker = new FooMaker(new Foo);
let foo2 = foomaker.foo; // Type "Foo", OK
let result1 = foomaker.foo.bar(); // Type "{bar: string}", OK
let result2 = foomaker.bar(); // Type "{}", ???
let result3 = foomaker.baz(); // I've seen comments about using a lambda... Not better
```

`result2` and `result3` are typed like the abstract `bar` function (`{}`). It seems that `this` isn't resolved as the concrete class `Foo` but as the abstract class `FooAbstract`. Whereas the type of `foo2` shows that the class `foo` property is resolved correctly.

What is going on? Do I do something the wrong way?

---

## update

As an afterthought, this case can be reformulated like that ([Test it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20bar%3A%20%27bar%27%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getThis()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Wrapper%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3CFOO%20extends%20%7B%20bar()%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%3E(foo%3AFOO)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20foo.bar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20wrapper%20%3D%20new%20Wrapper()%3B%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20(new%20Foo()).bar()%3B%0D%0Alet%20result2%20%3D%20wrapper.bar(new%20Foo())%3B%0D%0A)):

```
class Foo {
    bar() {
        return { bar: 'bar' };
    }

    getThis(): this {
        return this
    }
}

class Wrapper {  
    bar<FOO extends { bar(): {} }>(foo:FOO) {
        return foo.bar();
    }
}

let wrapper = new Wrapper();
let result = (new Foo()).bar();
let result2 = wrapper.bar(new Foo());
```

`result` has the type `{bar:string}`
`result2` has the type `{}` (from the interface).
`wrapper.bar` has the type `Wrapper.bar<Foo>(foo: Foo): {}`

With this sample, it's clearer that, even when knowing that `FOO` is typed as `Foo`, *Typescript* uses `FOO` definition and not its explicit type as `bar` return type.

---

## update 2

Ok, while fighting with typings, I think I leveled up. The concept is indeed that implicit typings in *Typescript* don't follow any inheritance model even when a type is deduced. Well, I still wonder *why* or *is it going to change*, but I'll have to cope with "it's like that". So in this case the type has to be explicit.

I found a simpler way to write his example ([try it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20FooAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20bar()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20extends%20FooAbstract%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20bar%3A%20%27bar%27%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FooMaker%3CFOO%20extends%20FooAbstract%2C%20BAR%3E%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20foo%3A%20FOO%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20BAR%20%7D%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%3ABAR%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.foo.bar()%20as%20BAR%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foomaker%20%3D%20new%20FooMaker(new%20Foo())%3B%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20foomaker.bar()%3B%0D%0A)):

```
abstract class FooAbstract {
    abstract bar(): {}
}

class Foo extends FooAbstract { 
    bar() { 
        return { bar: 'bar' };
    }
}

class FooMaker<FOO extends FooAbstract, BAR> {  
    constructor(public foo: FOO & { bar: () => BAR } ) {       
    }

    bar():BAR { 
        return this.foo.bar() as BAR;
    }
}

let foomaker = new FooMaker(new Foo());
let result = foomaker.bar();
```

`result` gets the type `{bar:string}` and no need to put generics everywhere. The stuff in the `FooMaker.constructor` parameter type could get cleaner by referring an interface with a generic.

Comment: Hmm, adding `const p = str => console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
p(result2);
p(result3);
p(result4);` to your test gives `3 x {"bar":"bar"}` into console. Can't reproduce the problem you are talking about. Please advise

Comment: @jevgenig That's not about the values, but about their types (and consequently typechecks, completion etc...). To observe the issue, click on the Typescript playground link (or paste into an IDE such as VSCode or WebStorm) and place the mouse cursor over the concerned variables.

Comment: I see now, thanks for clarification. `result2` has `any` type because `abstract bar` in your `FooAbstract` class, does not have return type defined. Try changing it to `abstract class FooAbstract {
    abstract bar(): { bar: string };
}`

Comment: @jevgenig Thanks for your proposal. However I'm not wondering how to make it work. Rather to have a better understanding of what the generics can and cannot do, and of the design limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean answer and example of what is needed to pass method return types.

## the issue

An object that embeds another object uses its internally declared type (in this case the abstract type) to determine its functions return type. Even when that object type is known (or explicitly declared).

In other words, Typescript type inference doesn't look inside the object methods to deduce a type.

## the solution

The only solution I found to handle that case is to associate generics to the methods/functions return types, and to match the object structure with them.

Based on my question **update 2** ([test it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TestInterface%3CASNUM%2C%20ASSTRING%2C%20ASOBJECT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asNum%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20ASNUM%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asString%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20ASSTRING%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20ASOBJECT%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BaseInterface%20extends%20TestInterface%3Cany%2C%20any%2C%20any%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Obj%20implements%20BaseInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20n%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asNum()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.n.toString()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bvalue%3A%20this.n%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Wrapper%3CT%20extends%20BaseInterface%2C%20ASNUM%2C%20ASSTRING%2C%20ASOBJECT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20obj%3A%20T%20%26%20TestInterface%3CASNUM%2C%20ASSTRING%2C%20ASOBJECT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asNum()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.obj.asNum()%20as%20ASNUM%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.obj.asString()%20as%20ASSTRING%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.obj.asObject()%20as%20ASOBJECT%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20w%20%3D%20new%20Wrapper(new%20Obj(5))%3B%0D%0Alet%20myNum%20%3D%20w.asNum()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20number%0D%0Alet%20myString%20%3D%20w.asString()%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20string%0D%0Alet%20myObject%20%3D%20w.asObject()%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20%7Bvalue%3A%20number%7D)):

```
interface TestInterface<ASNUM, ASSTRING, ASOBJECT> {
    asNum: () => ASNUM
    asString: () => ASSTRING
    asObject: () => ASOBJECT
}

interface BaseInterface extends TestInterface<any, any, any> { }

class Obj implements BaseInterface {
    constructor(private n: number) { 
    }

    asNum() {
        return this.n;
    }

    asString() {
        return this.n.toString();       
    }

    asObject() { 
        return {value: this.n};
    }
}

class Wrapper<T extends BaseInterface, ASNUM, ASSTRING, ASOBJECT> {
    constructor(private obj: T & TestInterface<ASNUM, ASSTRING, ASOBJECT>) {
    }

    asNum() {
        return this.obj.asNum() as ASNUM;
    }

    asString() {
        return this.obj.asString() as ASSTRING;
    }

    asObject() {
        return this.obj.asObject() as ASOBJECT;
    }
}

let w = new Wrapper(new Obj(5));
let myNum = w.asNum();       // type: number
let myString = w.asString(); // type: string
let myObject = w.asObject(); // type: {value: number}
```

The types are OK!

## alternatives

I didn't find a lot of things about that or that could help in the docs/upcoming features of *Typescript 2.3*.  Concerning the things that could possibly help to shape a better solution:

- There is a post about *variadic types* here, maybe this could help to improve such a sample (not sure though): https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453
- Concerning the `this` references, there's a mention about strongly typing this here when using the `--noImplicitThis` compilation option, and the `ThisType<T>` function to declare this explicitely. But apparently it's more about a function being aware of its embedding structure type, than following the object model flow. And it doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about how the type resolution works for the bar function:

```
bar() { 
    return this.foo.bar();
}
```

What is `this.foo`?  `FOO` or more precisely, a class that extends `FooAbstract`, because unlike the property `foo`, `bar` doesn't expose `FOO`.  The typing has to be determined before the actual type FOO is defined.

You would have to do something like this, if you really wanted to type it:

```
abstract class FooAbstract<T extends {}> {
    abstract bar(): T
}

class Foo extends FooAbstract<{ bar: string }> { 
    bar() { 
        return { bar: 'bar' };
    }
}

class FooMaker<FOO extends FooAbstract<BAR>, BAR> {  
    constructor(public foo: FOO) {}

    bar():BAR { 
        return this.foo.bar();
    }

    baz = (): BAR => {
        return this.foo.bar();
    }
}

let foo = new Foo();
let result = foo.bar();

let foomaker = new FooMaker<Foo, { bar: string}>(new Foo);
let foo2 = foomaker.foo; // Type "Foo", OK
let result1 = foomaker.foo.bar(); // Type "{bar: string}", OK
let result2 = foomaker.bar(); // Type "{bar: string}", OK
let result3 = foomaker.baz(); // Type "{bar: string}", OK
```

And unfortunetly, you have to explicitly define the type of FooMaker, but you do prevent something like this:

```
let foomaker = new FooMaker<Foo, { bar: number}>(new Foo);
```

Comment: :'( The answer I was afraid of. If I understand well, if `FooAbstract` has 10 functions such as `bar()`, or if there are many different classes extending `FooAbstract` (if `FooMaker` was a more sophisticated factory), my code would become an horrible mess. Or I would have to forget typings. Right?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The typing has to be determined before the actual type FOO is defined.". Not sure I get exactly how the typings are computed, or what are their limitations.

Comment: Properties are either implictly, or explicitly typed.There are no explicit typings for bar, so the implicit one is used, which is FooAbstract.bar's type, {}.  Foo is Typed as FOO which is the generic type, and defined as such

Comment: If all you're doing is extending an exiting type, you could just cast to it: `var result = (new FooMaker(new Foo) as Foo).bar() // works

Comment: Yes, I get implicit and explicit typings. But I was expecting Typescript to be better at implicitely deducing `FOO`'s type. Given that `FOO`'s actual type is passed via the constructor, that `result1` is OK and that `result2` somewhat outcomes to the same.
And no, I want to do more than calling `bar()`. Otherwise there would have been simpler solutions.
With an object paradigm over a prototype paradigm, hyeroglyphic syntax and a hard time to get typings over the most common patterns, I sometimes wonder why I use Typescript...
Well, thanks for the answer, let's validate that.

Comment: I don't see your example as a "Common Pattern"  I don't see it as all that useful... What you are really looking for is to define a property type as the type of another property, Oracle has this ability, but not TS.  The type has to be determined, or a Generic Type.

Comment: Ok , I accept my fate :) . If interested, I found a simpler way to write your example. See "update 2". And because I'm obstinated, I also opened another question here, with a (still minimal) example that maybe makes more sense and helped me to understand things clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505888/typescript-object-wrapping-typings-and-generics/43509473#43509473