# typescript export same interface name between built-in object and other

Tags: typescript, interface, export

I want to export interface wrapped Object.

```
interface Wrap<T> {
    original: T
}

export interface WrappedObject extends Wrap<Object> { //It is wrapped Object.

}

//It works
let a : WrappedObject = {
    original : {
        example:3
    }
};
console.log(a.original.hasOwnProperty("example"));
```

But If I change "WrappedObject" to "Object",
`Wrap<Object>` works like `Wrap<wrapped object>`.
Object refer to itself.

```
interface Wrap<T> {
    original: T
}

export interface Object extends Wrap<Object> { //It is wrapped Object.

}

//It doesn't work.
let a : Object = {
    original : {
        example:3
    }
};
console.log(a.original.hasOwnProperty("example"));

//But it work.
let a : Object;
a.original.original.original.original;
```

I want to make Object don't refer to itself.

Comment: where's the definition of `Other`? and if you create an interface that extends a class that implements itself, it's expected to get that error.

Comment: It's just a example, so Other interface is not important. I want to export interface that have name used by built-in object and that extends other interface with built-in object generic.

Comment: well, it would be easier to help with a minimum working example, and just by using what you provided I'm not getting the "recursive reference" error.. so something else has to be going on. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why you extend `object` with a `wrapper<object>` and expect that it doesn't refer to itself... after all, you're extending something with a wrapper of itself, so should refer itself, I think.

does this article help? [Typescript object wrapping, typings and generics [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505888/typescript-object-wrapping-typings-and-generics)